# Can I get the Mac OS version from the user agent?

Tags: php, macos

I have an app in different Mac OS versions - one for el Capitan and up and one for all OS versions below that.

Users (unfortunately) don't always know that they're on el Cap or Sierra and have trouble figuring it out.

On my download page I'd like to show them (if possible) which version to download and hence I'd like to use the User Agent string to do this.

It seems it can contain phrases like "Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3" - is this reliable or is there a standard for this? Can't find it on Apple.com. And if it is - what kind of shape can I determine it from?

Comment: https://www.whatismybrowser.com/developers/tools/user-agent-parser/browse/operating-system-name/mac-os-x-user-agents

Comment: thanks - saw that, but it is very outdated and no longer maintained

Comment: Each browser formats it differently, as you can see from the table at that site.

Comment: I'd expect each browser to continue in their general style. Some use `OS X ##_##_#` while some use `OS X ##.##.#`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you match the regular expression

```
/OS X 10[_.](\d+)/
```

Some browsers use `_` to separate the parts of the OS X release, while others use `.`, and this will match either format. The capture group will contain the OS X major release number. If it's `11` or higher then they should use the El Capitan version.

Comment: thanks - that sounds great - I'll check this out. I wasn't sure if this part is always sent or whether there are different versions out there (like the . and underscore).

Comment: You can't always rely on the user agent, since the user can spoof it. But if you're dealing with naive users and they're not using exotic browsers, it should be pretty reliable.